# Toast in onPostExecute() in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to post a toast in OnPostExecture in an Async.

Here is the what I have done but it doesn't log and it is not toasting.

```
protected class sendDetails extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Boolean>
{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
        }

        sendEmail();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) 
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Email Succesfully Sent...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        finish();
    }
}
```

I also tried the following:

Declaring Context:

```
 private Context mContext;
```

//Calling the Async

```
new sendDetails(mContext).execute();
```

//Async Code:

```
protected class sendDetails extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Boolean>
{

    public sendDetails(final Context context) 
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
        }

        sendEmail();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) 
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Email Succesfully Sent...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Both didn't work. How to toast from Async.. Can somebody help me fix this?

**Update:**

Changed according to JDJ, matiash & RajaReddy PolamReddy

remove Finish(); in onPreExecute.
And added the following in OnPostExecute:

```
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email Succesfully Sent...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 finish();
```

Thanks!

Comment: simply remover finish() and you done here , moreover you dont need to call runOnUiThread in onPostExecute method, that method call itself in in UI thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to call `runOnUiThread()` in `onPostExecute()` ... it's already on the UI thread at that point.

So your onPostExecute() should just look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) 
{
    Toast.makeText(mContext, 
                   "Email Succesfully Sent...", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And by `finish()`ing your activity in onPreExecute() before the background thread starts, after the background thread is done and onPostExecute() is called, the `mContext` in onPostExecute() that you're passing into the Toast constructor might not even be valid anymore.

Comment: I am not getting the toast if I directly add toast.

Comment: Did you try removing the call to finish() in onPreExecute() ?

Comment: Yep. I removed the finish and then added: Toast.makeText(main.this, 
"Email Succesfully Sent...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Remove the call to sendMail() and see if you get the Toast.

Comment: Yep. It is Working. there So I think it is problem somewhere in SendMail() Let me look into this and get back.

Comment: Good to hear.  I don't know what your `sendMail()` function is doing, but it's obviously taking a very long time and not returning :)

Comment: You are right. Checked the sendMail(); I had delay there for testing purpose. Which I forgot to remove and hence no toast or anything. Sorry guys my bad! Thanks a lot of JDJ. Everything working fine now!

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary to call `runOnUiThread()` from `onPostExecute()`. That method already runs on the UI thread.

Also, this:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    finish();
}
```

looks strange. You're finishing the activity before launching the task, is that correct?

Comment: Yep. It is correct. I want to close the screen immediately after I called the async.

Comment: After the call to async doInBackground, it's the onPostExecute() that is called and not the onPreExecute()

Comment: Yeah. I know. I don't want to show the screen immediately after the async is called and hence I put finish in preExecute

Answer (score 2):

You are `finishing` activity in `onPreExecute()` so context of that current is closing so toast will not work, remove that cde first.

AsyncTask will work like this

When an asynchronous task is executed, the tasks flows like this:

1. onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread
2. doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread
3. onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread
4. onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread

so remove finish from onPreExcute() and use it in onPostExcute() if you want, and one more thing no need to run on Ui thread in postExecute() method.

Comment: Did want to said but still I am not getting the toast.

Answer (score 2):

No need to write `runOnUiThread` method in post execute.

Try this

```
protected class sendDetails extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Boolean>
{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            sendEmail();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) 
    {
       Toast.makeText(mContext, "Email Succesfully Sent...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

In the class extending Async, I create a constructor and pass the calling activity's context to it. The I do some task in the background and return the result as a string. The string returned indicates whether the task was performed successfully or not. I create the toast in the onPostExecute() and it works fine. Here is the code for the same:

```
public class TaskInBackground extends AsyncTask<Map<Integer,Object>, Void, String> {

Context context;

public TaskInBackground(Context context)
{
    this.context=context;
}

/**
 * task to be executed in the background
 */
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected String doInBackground(Map<Integer, Object>... params) {
    Map<Integer, Object> taskRequested=params[0];
       switch(taskRequested)
        case(1):
             return("Success");
        case(2):
             return("Success");
        default:
        return "Invalid";           
    }

}

/**
 * post execution of background task, what needs to be done
 */
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public static void pushList(Activity context){
  static Context = mConext;

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

      Toast toast=Toast.makeText(mConext,"Succefully Updated Profile",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             toast.show();

  }
}
```

this code perfectly work for me and display toast msg.