# failed to toast on User interface when connection is timed out

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set timeout connection for my application. now when the timeout occurred i succeed to catch the exception but for some reason the Toast failed.
i know tat this thread is working on the background but i would like to implement the toast in the current class because many other classes implementing it.
the error i got is:

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   Looper.prepare()

and this is my code:

```
public class DBcontroller extends AsyncTask <List<NameValuePair>, Void, String>{
 private static String url = "";
        private  Context context = null ;
        public AsyncResponse delegate= null;

        private PropertyReader propertyReader;
        private Properties properties;

        public DBcontroller(Context mycontext,AsyncResponse myresponse) {
            context = mycontext;
            delegate = myresponse;
            propertyReader = new PropertyReader(context);
            properties = propertyReader.getMyProperties("config.properties");
            url = properties.getProperty("url");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            delegate.preProcess();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... params) {
            return postDataToServer(params[0]);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resStr) {
            super.onPostExecute(resStr);
            delegate.handleResponse(resStr);
        }
        private String postDataToServer(List<NameValuePair> list) {
            //check
            for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
                Log.d("responseString", list.get(i).toString());
            //check

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

            String responseString = null;
            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.d("responseString1", responseString);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
                //Here Connection TimeOut excepion
                Toast.makeText(this.context, "Your connection timedout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(responseString!= null)
                 Log.d("responseString2", responseString);
            return responseString;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is show the `Toast` inside `onPostExecute()`, you will use a boolean variable like `isConnectTimeoutException`

```
...   
...
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
      isConnectTimeoutException = true;      
    }
...
...
```

then  **it's already on the UI thread at that point**.:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resStr) {
        super.onPostExecute(resStr);
        delegate.handleResponse(resStr);
        if(isConnectTimeoutException){ 
           Toast.makeText(this.context, "Your connection timedout",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }
```

Comment: isConnectTimeoutException is boolean?

Comment: its an example, create a variable (isConnectTimeoutException) to establish if ConnectTimeoutException has occurred, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566376/toast-in-onpostexecute-in-android other method is using runOnUiThread() method.

Answer (score 0):

Add Toast inside runOnUiThread which is safe to create or update UI from worker thread

```
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Your connection timedout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
Handler handler =  new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    handler.post( new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Your Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
    });
```

Where you have to show `toast` in `doInBackground` method.